# how to detect that avif is supported or not in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, contentful, avif

I am trying to optimize the image by formatting that to avif. But some of the browser's are not supporting avif.

So I created a utility function like this

```
  function isAvifSupported() {
    let returnValue;
    const avif = new Image();
    avif.src =
      "data:image/avif;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBhdmlmAAAAAGF2aWZtaWYxbWlhZk1BMUIAAADybWV0YQAAAAAAAAAoaGRscgAAAAAAAAAAcGljdAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGxpYmF2aWYAAAAADnBpdG0AAAAAAAEAAAAeaWxvYwAAAABEAAABAAEAAAABAAABGgAAAB0AAAAoaWluZgAAAAAAAQAAABppbmZlAgAAAAABAABhdjAxQ29sb3IAAAAAamlwcnAAAABLaXBjbwAAABRpc3BlAAAAAAAAAAIAAAACAAAAEHBpeGkAAAAAAwgICAAAAAxhdjFDgQ0MAAAAABNjb2xybmNseAACAAIAAYAAAAAXaXBtYQAAAAAAAAABAAEEAQKDBAAAACVtZGF0EgAKCBgANogQEAwgMg8f8D///8WfhwB8+ErK42A=";
    avif.onload = function () {
        returnValue = true
    };
    return returnValue;
  }
```

but when I try to call this function it always returns undefined. But when I use the function that has been provided in avif site. it works fine. Below is the code for it

```
function AddClass(class) { document.documentElement.classList.add(class) };
var avif = new Image();
avif.src = "data:image/avif;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBhdmlmAAAAAGF2aWZtaWYxbWlhZk1BMUIAAADybWV0YQAAAAAAAAAoaGRscgAAAAAAAAAAcGljdAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGxpYmF2aWYAAAAADnBpdG0AAAAAAAEAAAAeaWxvYwAAAABEAAABAAEAAAABAAABGgAAAB0AAAAoaWluZgAAAAAAAQAAABppbmZlAgAAAAABAABhdjAxQ29sb3IAAAAAamlwcnAAAABLaXBjbwAAABRpc3BlAAAAAAAAAAIAAAACAAAAEHBpeGkAAAAAAwgICAAAAAxhdjFDgQ0MAAAAABNjb2xybmNseAACAAIAAYAAAAAXaXBtYQAAAAAAAAABAAEEAQKDBAAAACVtZGF0EgAKCBgANogQEAwgMg8f8D///8WfhwB8+ErK42A=";
avif.onload = function () { AddClass("avif") };
avif.onerror = function () {
  var webp = new Image();
  webp.src = "data:image/webp;base64,UklGRhoAAABXRUJQVlA4TA0AAAAvAAAAEAcQERGIiP4HAA==";
  webp.onload = function () { AddClass("webp") }
}
```

But the above-defined function adds the css at the top level of dom. Instead of adding the class, It has to return true or false. So that i am able to handle that easily like this.

```
let updatedImageUrl = isAvifSupported() ? `${imageUrl}?fm=avif` ? imageUrl
```

But I don't know, how to fix this. Please recommend a solution.

Comment: [Microsoft Edge's lack of AVIF support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75459594/) is a disgrace! I wish more people would complain about this to them. Shamefully, another way to detect lack of support it to merely detect Microsoft Edge. They're practically the only browser not supporting this fantastic image format (where very small files serve great quality images). This feels like Internet Explorer: slow adoption of modern standards. However, in this case, they're going out their way to remove AVIF support. Chromium, the base of Edge, has AVIF support by default; M$ removes it. ANGER!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below functionality will work fine. It is an extended answer version of @Stefan Judis. I modified this depending upon my project

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const url =
  "https://images.ctfassets.net/{space_id}/1WJFyl9C8q18KI6OQG7mPu/{unique_name}/name.jpg";

const ImageFormat = () => {
  const [imageFormat, setImageFormat] = useState("");

  function addImageProcess(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => resolve("avif");
      img.onerror = () => {
        const webp = new Image();
        webp.src =
          "data:image/webp;base64,UklGRhoAAABXRUJQVlA4TA0AAAAvAAAAEAcQERGIiP4HAA==";
        webp.onload = async () => {
          resolve("webp");
        };

        webp.onerror = () => {
          reject("");
        };
      };
      img.src = src;
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function logImageFormat(imageUrl) {
      let imageFormatValue = await addImageProcess(imageUrl);
      setImageFormat(`${url}?fm=${imageFormatValue}&w=3500`);
    }

    logImageFormat(
      "data:image/avif;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBhdmlmAAAAAGF2aWZtaWYxbWlhZk1BMUIAAADybWV0YQAAAAAAAAAoaGRscgAAAAAAAAAAcGljdAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGxpYmF2aWYAAAAADnBpdG0AAAAAAAEAAAAeaWxvYwAAAABEAAABAAEAAAABAAABGgAAAB0AAAAoaWluZgAAAAAAAQAAABppbmZlAgAAAAABAABhdjAxQ29sb3IAAAAAamlwcnAAAABLaXBjbwAAABRpc3BlAAAAAAAAAAIAAAACAAAAEHBpeGkAAAAAAwgICAAAAAxhdjFDgQ0MAAAAABNjb2xybmNseAACAAIAAYAAAAAXaXBtYQAAAAAAAAABAAEEAQKDBAAAACVtZGF0EgAKCBgANogQEAwgMg8f8D///8WfhwB8+ErK42A="
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">{imageFormat}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageFormat;
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your snippet is that you're not taking the asynchronous call into consideration.

`onload` will be called after the function returns. To work around this, you have to either provide a callback and implement promises as the example below shows.

```
function isAvifSupported() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      var image = new Image();
  
      image.onload = image.onerror = function() {
        resolve(image.width === 2);
      };
  
      image.src = "data:image/avif;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBhdmlmAAAAAGF2aWZtaWYxbWlhZk1BMUIAAADybWV0YQAAAAAAAAAoaGRscgAAAAAAAAAAcGljdAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGxpYmF2aWYAAAAADnBpdG0AAAAAAAEAAAAeaWxvYwAAAABEAAABAAEAAAABAAABGgAAAB0AAAAoaWluZgAAAAAAAQAAABppbmZlAgAAAAABAABhdjAxQ29sb3IAAAAAamlwcnAAAABLaXBjbwAAABRpc3BlAAAAAAAAAAIAAAACAAAAEHBpeGkAAAAAAwgICAAAAAxhdjFDgQ0MAAAAABNjb2xybmNseAACAAIAAYAAAAAXaXBtYQAAAAAAAAABAAEEAQKDBAAAACVtZGF0EgAKCBgANogQEAwgMg8f8D///8WfhwB8+ErK42A=";
    });
}

isAvifSupported().then(console.log);
```

As inspiration, I adjusted [the standard modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/img/avif.js#L19-L30) snippet to fit your use case and used your dummy image.

Keep in mind that because you have to use an async call the feature detect has to be async, too.

```
isAvifSupported().then(
  isSupported => {
    const updatedImageUrl = isSupported ?
      `${imageUrl}?fm=avif` :
      imageUrl;
  }
);
```

Depending on your project you might need to refactor some things to implement the promise (or callback) solution, but unfortunately, there's no way to check avif support synchronously.

Comment: I tested this, and it detected AVIF support in Firefox and Chromium. And, it even detected Microsoft Edge's disgraceful lack of support that is worthy of more complaint than they've received so far. Please help push this through; complain about it to them if you have time.